# convert from Stream<@Nullable T> to Stream<@NonNull T> using stream api

Tags: java, checker-framework

I use CheckerFramework

How could I remove nulls from Stream and got collection of @NonNull objects?

```
Stream<@Nullable T> -> (remove nulls) -> Stream<@NonNull T>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is code that does it.

```
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.NonNull;
import org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.Nullable;

class RemoveNullsFromStream {

  @SuppressWarnings("nullness") // Nullness Checker is not hard-coded with
                  // implementation details of filter and Objects::nonNull
  <T>
  Stream<@NonNull T> removeNullsFromStream(Stream<@Nullable T> arg) {
    return arg.filter(Objects::nonNull);
  }

}
```

Note the use of `@SuppressWarnings`, because the Nullness Checker is conservative:  it issues a warning whenever it cannot definitively prove the code is safe.  In general, the output of `filter` is the same as its input; when the argument to `filter` is `Objects::nonNull` is a special case.

That special-case could be hard-coded into the Nullness Checker, and that would make the Nullness Checker more precise.  This behavior is not currently special-cased, so you use `@SuppressWarnings` instead.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But SuppressWarnings look ugly.
I tried arg.map(Optional::ofNullable).filter(Optional::isPresent).map(Optional::get) but it still returns List<@Nullable T>. Is it an error of CF?

Comment: To me, that long expression looks worse than a simple call to `removeNullsFromStream`.  The behavior is sound and conservative:  in general, `filter` returns the same type as its argument.  Think about how you know the result is `List<@Nullable>`, and then try to express the steps of your argument in the type system; if you cannot, then `@SuppressWarnings` is inherently necessary.

Comment: How about arg.filter(Objects::nonNull).map(t -> (@NonNull T)t)
Why it doesn't produce Stream<@NonNull T>?

Comment: This looks like a [bug](https://github.com/typetools/checker-framework/issues/1032); the call to `map` does produce `Stream<@NonNull String>` for a concrete type like `String`, but it doesn't work for a type argument such as `T`.